# How does this javascript object modification work? I don't understand the scope, It doesn't persist

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using Express, Node.js and a Mongo DB. I've simplified this code somewhat from my actual code to try to cut out the noise, I hope it makes sense.

My basic problem is that I'm modifying an object and I am expecting the data change to persist across client-server calls, but it isn't. The comments explain more.

```
// server side routes.js

var LM = require('./modules/login-manager'); // database accessing functions
var DM = require('./modules/data-manager'); // database accessing functions

module.exports = function (app) {

  app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    // LM.manualLogin does a MongoDB call that looks fine, returns the expected data
    LM.manualLogin(req.body['user'], req.body['pass'], function (e, o) {
      if (!o) {
        res.status(400).send(e);
      } else {
        req.session.user = o;
        // calculateRank adds arbitrary fields to the user object
        // this change persists to POST /dashboard
        calculateRank(req.session.user);
        // DM.getListOfData() does a Mongo DB call that looks fine
        // and returns the expected data in o
        DM.getListOfData(function (e, o) {
          if (!o) {
            res.status(400).send(e);
          } else {
            // availableData doesn't already exist. This assignment
            // operation looks good
            // in the debugger, but "availableData" is NOT in the 
            // req.session when we get to POST /dashboard
            req.session.availableData = o;
          }
        });

        res.status(200).send(o);
      }
    });
  });

  app.get('/dashboard', function (req, res) {
    if (req.session.user == null) {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
    else {
      // "availableData" is not there!
      // but changes to req.session.user are
      res.render('dashboard', {
        user: req.session.user,
        data: req.session.availableData
      });
    }
  });
}

// client side
$('#login').ajaxForm({
  beforeSubmit: function (formData, jqForm, options) {
    formData.push({
      name: 'remember-me',
      value: $('.button-rememember-me-glyph').hasClass('glyphicon-ok')
    });
    return true;
  },
  success: function (responseText, status, xhr, $form) {
    if (status == 'success') window.location.href = '/dashboard';
  },
  error: function (e) {
    // login error
  }
});
```

So I click my login button that drives the client-side ajax function. Server side, I get the POST / and when that returns, client side redirects to /dashboard. The problem is that server side, in POST /dashboard some of my data is missing. The thing I really don't understand is that the data set by "req.session.user = o;" and "calculateRank(req.session.user)" persists. The data set by "req.session.availableData = o;" doesn't, in POST /dashboard it is as if the operation never happened (but the other two did). When I debug that assignment operation it looks fine and I can see the data in the req object.

Can anyone help explain this to me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending the response, `res.status(200).send(o);`, before `req.session.availableData = o;` has had time to run, since **it's an async operation**.

Sending the response inside the `getListOfData` callback would fix your problem.

Comment: ugh, of course. I feel real dumb about that one now. My mind just sees those in-line functions as part of the current function, gotta get used to that. Thank you!